# Install Logstash on Windows

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

Trying to install logstash as windows service. All works when i manually run it from CMD like so:

```
C:\Elastic\Logstash\bin\logstash -f c:\Elastic\Logstash\config\logstash-sample.conf
```

I see that file changes are updated and posted to console (per .conf file console output)

However, when i install Logstash as windows service:

```
sc create Logstash binpath="\"C:\Elastic\Logstash\bin\logstash\" -f \"c:\Elastic\Logstash\config\logstash-sample.conf\""
```

It creates windows service but will fail when starting it:
[image]

Logstash log:

> [2019-04-15T14:40:29,605][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ]
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because
>   of an error: (SystemExit) exit

When I try to install logstash with NSSM like below, it runs, but does not work:

```
nssm.exe install logstash "C:\Elastic\Logstash\bin\logstash.bat" "agent -f C:\Elastic\Logstash\config\logstash-sample.conf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:
The problem I was having is due to "agent" keyword. In CMD i ran this:

```
nssm edit logstash
```

Then I got the following window and modified Arguments:
[image]